# How can I define a bigint type in a php nusoap webservice?

Tags: php, service, nusoap

I am using php nusoap to create a webservice. I need define a method which return a bigint number (files's size in bytes). It doesn't exist a xsd type bigger than integer. I've looked for how to create a simpletype with a int basetype and a value maxinclusive restriction, but it isn't possible. How can I do it?